# Add link to a file to download in CKAN

Tags: ckan

I would like to add a link to a pdf file to download, in my case to add the link to download in my footer.

I have tried several options, but I get always a link to a internal page in the portal

For instance, if I add a link like this:

```
<p><a href="/user_manual.pdf" style="text-decoration: none; color:#B6B6B6">User Manual</a></p>
```

I get an error, because it trying to reach an internal page.

I'm putting this kind of files in:

```
/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-myextension/ckanext/myextension/templates/user_manual.pdf
```

Any suggestions
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To add custom static files to your CKAN site you should create a new directory to public path. For more information check https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/theming/static-files.html?highlight=public

Comment: I second this comment, it's the way to go about adding static assets to CKAN extensions (such as your "myextension"). Add the folder, add the file, update your extension plugin.py then you can link to the file in your footer.